# How to match two columns value with the another two columns by using Excel Formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to match Column A and Column B data with With Column C and Column D on the same sheet. The order of data is different and is redundant. I am trying to implement the following logic.

IF A11 & B11 (PAIR 1) matches (PAIR 2) in any row then copy and paste C11.

I am using this formula but it is not giving the exact output that I am looking for.

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(MATCH(E11,$A$11:$A$30,0),MATCH(F11,$B$11:$B$30,0)),C11,"")," ")
```

I want the output to look like this.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Please check my formula where i am doing wrong? Please suggest me the correct formula. Thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9ReQ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have O365, you can use:

```
=FILTER($C$11:$C$29,(E11=$A$11:$A$29)*(F11=$B$11:$B$29))
```

If you have an earlier version, try:

```
=INDEX($C$11:$C$30,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/((E11=$A$11:$A$29)*(F11=$B$11:$B$29))*ROW($A$11:$A$29),1)-10)
```

The `10` at the end of the formula is an adjustment for the first row (actually the first row of data -1).  Since the data starts in Row 11, we need to subtract 10 to return the correct value.

Comment: Rosendfeld Thanks bro it is working perfectly.